# How do I solve this template syntax error on django

Tags: django-templates, syntax-error

I'm getting this error --> **Invalid block tag on: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?**

I made sure to indent and putting space correctly and yes I do have latest version of pycharm.

What would make it work correctly?

```
{% extends 'mc_application_folder/base.html' %}

{$ block content %}

<p>Topics: {{ topic }}</p>

<p>Entries:</p>
<ul>
{% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
        <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
        <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </li>
{% empty %}
    <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I don't think we need {%endblock content%} but only {% endblock %}

Comment: Hi, I tried that too but still same error.. I even tried deleting .html file and re-wrote my code with content and without it but still same issue arises.

Comment: Then the error may be in base.html file

Comment: please upload your base.html also

Comment: Also there is a typo in your code. You are using $ instead of % at {% block content %} on the top

Comment: I also had the typo in my answer as i copy pasted your code. Edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is just because of the closing tag `{%endblock content%}`. We don't need to specify `content` there but simply use `{% endblock %}`.

Full code here;

```
{% extends 'mc_application_folder/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>Topics: {{ topic }}</p>

<p>Entries:</p>
<ul>
{% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
        <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
        <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </li>
{% empty %}
    <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I saw my typo $ instead of %..I will try to fix it and run it after my work. Standby for result!

Comment: It was the typo issue as you already guessed..dang it!! I learned a lesson of checking typo mistakes..anyway thank you Irfan, your answer helped me to solve my problem!